# What is the difference in usage "new" while fetching Bookshelf.js models?

Tags: javascript, promise, bookshelf.js, knex.js

Bookshelf.js documentation has code examples with "new" and without "new":

Here http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-hasMany

```
let Author = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'authors',
  books: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Book);
  }
});

// select * from `authors` where id = 1
// select * from `books` where author_id = 1
Author.where({id: 1}).fetch({withRelated: ['books']}).then(function(author) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(author.related('books')));
});
```

But here http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-fetch

```
let Book = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'books',
  editions: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Edition);
  },
  chapters: function{
    return this.hasMany(Chapter);
  },
  genre: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Genre);
  }
})

new Book({'ISBN-13': '9780440180296'}).fetch({
  withRelated: [
    'genre', 'editions',
    { chapters: function(query) { query.orderBy('chapter_number'); }}
  ]
}).then(function(book) {
  console.log(book.related('genre').toJSON());
  console.log(book.related('editions').toJSON());
  console.log(book.toJSON());
});
```

So what is the difference?

Comment: Note that in the first example, `X.where()` is used. It's not just that `new` isn't used, a different method of getting an instance is used. I think if you read about about what `.where` does, you will understand the difference (do you know what `new X()` does in JavaScript?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No difference.

`Model.fetch`, `Model.query`, `Model.where` and `Model.fetchAll` are shorthands for:

```
Model[method] = function(...args) {
  return Model.forge()[method](...args);
}
```

And `Model.forge` is a shorthand for `new`.

```
Model.forge = function(...args) {
  return new this.constructor(...args);
}
```